# Use of missing as compund adjective

Tags: adjectives

When I ask someone who is missing one finger I think I should say ;

> How many finger are you missing ?

But I couldn’t understand why we use missing before one finger as is the case with sentence below

> I am missing one finger .

Isn’t it used as compund adjective .I mean shouldn’t we say ;

> I am one finger missing .

Comment: Is missing here not being used as a verb, in the meaning of 'to lack'?

Comment: I thought it is adjective . This is why I asked this question. Then you mean One piece of puzzle is missing . This one is adjective but I am one missing one finger . Here it is verb and present continuos tense .

Comment: That would make sense to me. Generally 'to miss' in that meaning is obsolete, but it is idiomatic so it would make sense. Either way, you can understand its grammatical use in this meaning by thinking of it as a verb

Comment: Thanks you so much.

Comment: @JacobLee-Hart Why do you think the meaning of *missing* as "lacking" is obsolete? "Missing a heart" is a common trope for lacking empathy.

Comment: @user105719 Looking at a dictionary, and I can't think of any other use of it really. I mean you only use it with the progressive tense, which makes it seem a bit idiomatic.

Comment: @JacobLee-Hart May I suggest that most dictionaries won't help you unless they're historical dictionaries like the *OED*. You have to check modern usage. For instance you can find the book *An Awareness of What is **Missing** Faith and Reason in a Post-Secular Age* by J Habermas, published in 2014. *Missing* in this sense is a nonfinite verb form, i.e., it doesn't carry tense. It's a present participle; it carries the sense of ongoing feeling or action.

Comment: @JacobLee-Hart You're right that *missing* in its sense of lacking has picked up a separate, idiomatic meaning. When you say "I keep missing John," you mean either you're pining for John or you've got bad aim, not that John is a lack in your life.  The same thing has happened to *saying* when it mean an aphorism.